# How did Sony VTRs use 'jog' data in 9-pin protocol?

Tags: sony, control, serial, rs-422

This is pretty obscure, but there may be a fellow old-timer here with experience in VTRs and edit controllers.

In Sony P2 ("9-pin") protocol, the Jog, Shuttle and Var commands use two data bytes to express the desired speed, in a convoluted way that yields a range of .01x to 999,728x play speed (64 00 gives 1x play, for example).

Jog is a low speed affair, so most of this range is wasted. So my question is: Do 'Jog' (and Var) use a limited range of data bytes, or do they scale the speed after computing it from the full range of data bytes?

Any insights welcome.